Cypress script unable to perform conditional exit looping when nested loops are used
I am newbie with Cypress. My requirement is to use 2 loops where the script has to abort both loops when a certain condition is met. The condition in question is when the required element #scoreCard is found. To terminate the method, I am using few exit criteria flags exitFLag and index, which are set respectively to true and 100 when #scoreCard element is found in the inner loop.
However, even though the exit flags are being updated in the inner loop, these are still set to their original values when the outer loop si reached. Please help me to fix the issue. I this this has something to do with the nature of async and sync in cypress/javascript.
Can anyone please guide me on how I can resolve this issue. How can I make both the loops stop iterating or even returning from the method when the scorecard element is found?
Here is my code below:
testMethod(){
    const _sysIdArr=['123','456', '789', '121','232','343','454','565','676','787','898'];

    cy.get("#id").then($el => {
    cy.log("Records count - " + $el.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < $el.length; i++) {

        let exitFLag = false;

        if (i === $el.length) {
            for (let index = 0; index < _sysIdArr.length; index++) {

                cy.visit(url);
                cy.wait(5000);

                cy.window()
                    .then($window =>
                        $window
                            .document
                            .querySelector("#scoreCard")).then((el) => {
                                
                                 //exit both the loops if scoreCard element is found on                         the page
                                if (!(Object.is(el, null))) {
                                    exitFLag = true; //set exitflag to true
                                    _sysIdArr.splice(0, _sysIdArr.length) //empty the array
                    index=100; //set the loop variable to the value beyond the array length
                                    cy.log("exitFlag @inner loop : " + exitFLag)  //outputs true 
                                    cy.log("_sysIdArr @inner loop : " + _sysIdArr.length) //outputs 0 as we emptied array
                                    cy.log("index @inner loop : " + index) // outputs 100
                                    return; //returns from inner loop. Actually I tried using 'break' statement, but it gives an error
                                }

                            })
                cy.log("exitFlag @outer loop : " + exitFLag) //prints false
                cy.log("_sysIdArr @outer loop : " + _sysIdArr.length) //prints 11
                cy.log("index @outer loop : " + index) // prints the original loop variable value
                                if(exitFlag || _sysIdArr.length===0 || index ===100){return;}

            }
        }
    }
}

